# how to order by other column in the group by?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have the following articles mysql table:

```
id | date
 1 | 2013-02-16 00:00:00
 2 | 2013-02-17 00:00:00
```

I want to get a comma separated list of the ids (1,2) and the last date value (2013-02-17 00:00:00)

I use the following query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id),date FROM articles ORDER BY date DESC
```

The query selects the first date value it encounters (2013-02-16 00:00:00), how to make it select the last one instead?

Thanks

Comment: i want to get the latest date (most recent) so order desc should be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select group_concat(id), 
       max(date) as max_date
from your_table
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b85e/2)

Comment: i don't want to group because i just want a comma separated list of ids not each row individually..thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: Try adding a `limit 1` to you query including the `group by`

Comment: this will yield only `1`, i want a comma separated list of ids (1,2) along with the date of the last article

Answer (score 2):

What about use `MAX`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id),MAX(date) 
FROM articles
```

And the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e957/3

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id),date FROM articles ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: i want the latest date (most recent) so desc should be used